# Apache rewrite rule (mod_proxy or mod_rewrite)

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

I need to rewrite a incoming request for a particular file. The file will have a suffix of .rtfx and I need to remove the host (http://www.host.com/) and replace it with another.

Request *.rtfx file
Request is http://www.host.com/blah/blah/rtfx.com
Replace http://www.host.com/ with something else.

I have tried to figure out how to do this with mod_proxy, but it looks like mod_rewrite is my only option.

Answer (score 0):

With mod_proxy:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(blah/blah/.*\.rtfx)   http://www.somewhereelse.com/$1
```

With mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^/(blah/blah/.*\.rtfx)     http://www.somewhereelse.com/$1 [P,L]
```

Put this in the server config for your host...